# Android BitmapFactory doesn't get from inputstream on AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, inputstream

**I get Inputstream file in `doInBackground` then return this inputstream. this my code**

```
 class PhotoAddTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, InputStream> {
    public PhotoAddTask(ProgressDialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Doing something, please wait.");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(Void... voids) {

           InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                String url = "http://some-url"
                inputStream = getImageFromURL(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return inputStream;
       }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }    
         photoImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));

    }
}

public BufferedHttpEntity getImageFromURL(String fileUrl) {
    BufferedHttpEntity breader = null;
    try {
        HttpGet httpRequest = null;

        httpRequest = new HttpGet(fileUrl);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = null;
        response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        breader = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return breader;
```

Q: I get Inputstream file in doInBackground then return this inputstream, 
and I set

`photoImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream))`

in `onPostExecute()` but

`BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)` return `null`.

What could be wrong with this code?

Comment: What is your image encoded format? Furthermore, I suggest that you do the `decodeStream` call in the `doInBackground` function (just to optimize UI)

Answer (score 1):

For just load images into imageViews I reccommend you to use Picasso library instead of AsyncTask.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
String imageURL = "http://IMAGE_URL";

Picasso.with(context)
       .load(imageURL)
       .into(imageView);
```

Picasso handles the bitmap memory problems, performance and cache.

Also you need to add the library to gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I need that methods. because i only used AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Can you show method `getImageFromURL()` ? Please avoid this kind of solution. If you want to fetch photo and then set ImageView please use Glide or Picasso.

Comment: this should be a comment...not an answer

Comment: Actually, it's good answer. @Messi Use Glide or Picasso, don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 why ? I also add solution for his problem, so it should not be a comment.

Comment: need not use AsyncTask on Picasso loading image

Comment: But. i have question. why file didn't get in inputstream object onPostExcute